# update ContentVersion using rest API

Tags: rest-api, contentversion

I have some data on the ContentVersion object. I want to update the field **VersionData** in the ContentVersion object using REST API. Here is some more detail about the API.

Endpoint: https://mysite.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/ID

Payload:

```
{ "Title": "Update TEST", 
 "ReasonForChange":"Marketing materials updated",
 "PathOnClient" : "Q1 Sales Brochure.pdf", 
"versionData":"[...]" }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: By definition, `ContentVersion` is an instance of each file version so it can't be updated, only created as a _new version_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in this [SFSE link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/733/isnt-contentversion-versiondata-updateable-amendable), It seems ContentVersion can't be updated.

But you can create a new `ContentVersion` and attach to the same `ContentDocument` as below with the [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) API.

URL - */services/data/vXX.0/sobjects/ContentVersion*

Method - *POST*

Body :

```
{
    "ContentDocumentId" : "069.....",
    "PathOnClient" : "sfdclogo.jpg",
    "ReasonForChange" : "New Version",
    "VersionData": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJ...//The content or body of the file (Base64 encoded) 
}
```

Reference - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-upload-document-salesforce-files-using-rest-api-subhajit-goswami